# Maximum number of points XTK can render?

Tags: xtk

As per [http://lessons.goxtk.com/09/][1]

[1]: http://lessons.goxtk.com/09/ i need to use a .vtk file with 15,000 points. It took too long to load the points and finally firefox crashes.

Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to just display the points without converting them to spheres so basically just do that:

```
var ren = new X.renderer3D();
ren.init();

var points = new X.mesh();
points.file = 'yourfile.vtk';

ren.add(points);
ren.render();
```

If this works, you can adjust the point size to make the points appear bigger http://api.goxtk.com/mesh.html#pointsize_get

Also, can you show your problems inside a JSFiddle?

Comment: It works. Now i can render mesh with very large number of point data. Thanks a lot for the hints.